# Sending messages from devtools panel to new tab in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I should send data from my devtools panel to tab. When I send a message using chrome.tabs.sendMessage, why is it not received?

panel.js

```
$(".options").on("submit", "form", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  newTabPort = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "new tab" });
  newTabPort.postMessage($(this).serializeArray());
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  });

  if (port.name == "new tab") {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('page/request_sending_page.html')}, function(tab) {});
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      var activeTab = tabs[0];
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {message: "olololololololo"});
    });
  }
});
```

my_extension_page.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  $("body").append("Hello world <br>");
  $("body").append(request.message);
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: It is page of my extension.
This is the code that executes when the this page, do it in a file
I accidentally wrote the wrong name when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Chrome API with function callbacks are asynchronous, so in your code `chrome.tabs.create` is executed after the entire function code has completed, thus `chrome.tabs.query` on the next line doesn't see the newly created tab.

1. Move the code that should work with the result of the asynchronous call into the callback
2. Wait for the new tab to be completely loaded before sending the message
3. There's no need for `chrome.extension.getURL` when you open the tab from background script.

---

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: '/page/request_sending_page.html'}, function(tab) {
    var newTabId = tab.id;
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function onComplete(tabId, info, tab) {
        if (tabId == newTabId && info.status == "complete") {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onComplete);
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {message: "olololololololo"});
        }
    });
});
```

P.S. manifest.json: `"permissions": ["tabs"]`